# How are this voltage source and resistor (separated from each other by a capacitor) re-imagined as a resistive voltage source?

Tags: operational-amplifier, capacitor, series, voltage-source

I'm trying to implement a wave digital filter from this research paper:

[Emulation of Operational Amplifiers and Diodes in Audio Distortion Circuits](https://aaltodoc.aalto.fi/bitstream/handle/123456789/14420/article4.pdf?sequence=7)

*R. C. D. de Paiva, S. D Angelo, J. Pakarinen, and V. Välimäki. Emulation of Operational Amplifiers and Diodes in Audio Distortion Circuits. IEEE Trans. Circ. Systems II: Express Briefs, vol. 59, no. 10, pp. 688 692, October 2012.*

In Fig. 4(a) on page 3, *Vin* is shown running through a 1uF capacitor, the other connected to *V+* of the op-amp. There is also a 10kΩ resistance between *V+* and ground.

---

[image]

---

In Fig. 5(a) on page 4, the wave digital filter implementation of this circuit used in the paper is given. Here, the positive terminal subcircuit is re-imagined as a 10kΩ resistive voltage source in series with the 1uF capacitor.

---

[image]

---

I don't see how this transformation is valid - I know I can assume there's no current into the positive terminal of the op-amp, but even still both the voltage source *Vin* and the 10kΩ resistor are connected to ground.

(When I implemented this myself the results were *mostly* accurate compared to a SPICE simulation of the original circuit. It could also just be that the DSP math works out for WDF voltage source objects)

Comment: You are right; this transformation is not valid... Vin is connected (through 1microF capacitor in series) in parallel to 10 k resistor and V+ (non-inverting input).